# drawRect produces jaggy lines (played around with antialiasing - to no avail)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, retina-display, drawrect

I am currently clipping my context to a triangle and when I draw an image within that triangle I get jaggy edges.They really look terrible on the retina display (have not tested on other devices yet). I have tried to set `UIViewEdgeAntialiasing` in my application's .plist file to `YES` and I made sure to enable antialiasing for my context.

This is the code:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, YES);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, YES);

CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(1, 1), 3, UIColorFromRGB(0x000000, 0.12).CGColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);

CGMutablePathRef rightCornerCutOut = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(rightCornerCutOut, NULL, self.offset, self.offset);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(rightCornerCutOut, NULL, self.cutOutSize-self.offset, self.offset);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(rightCornerCutOut, NULL, self.offset, self.cutOutSize-self.offset);
CGPathCloseSubpath(rightCornerCutOut);

CGContextAddPath(context, rightCornerCutOut);
CGContextFillPath(context);

CGContextAddPath(context, rightCornerCutOut);
CGContextClip(context);

CGRect imgRect = CGRectMake(0,0,self.cutOutSize,self.cutOutSize);
[myImage drawInRect:imgRect];

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

[image: Jaggy line]

Comment: This code is actually in `drawRect:`, and you aren't calling it directly?

Comment: @Wain Yes it is in `-drawRect:`, and no I am not calling it directly.

Comment: It might help to post a picture of what you're getting.

Comment: @ipmcc I have added an image. Please take a look.

Comment: Did you try putting the `CGContextSetShouldAntialias` call after `CGContextSaveGState`?

Comment: @DanyJoumaa yes I tried that before, to no avail.

Comment: @MartinE. It looks like you might not have a color to antialias against.  What if you fill the whole view with white before drawing anything else?